# How can I set the primary key value to other col in table when I insert a new row in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ-to-SQL class. I am inserting a new row using LINQ method `object.InsertOnSubmit()`.

I need to set same value which is generate by SQL Server (using `Identity`) for table primary key column.

Now I need the same value at the time of inserting new row into table. And set the same value for other column in the same table at the time of insert only.

As I cannot update as after inserting because table has UPDATE TRIGGER.

I tried the following

```
_db.EmpNews.InsertOnSubmit(_EmpNews);
...
_db.DisplaySeq = _EmpNews.ID;
...
_db.SubmitChanges();
```

Where `ID` is the auto-generated (`Identity`) column.

Comment: I actually came up with a decent 'hack' for this. I just add a `SecondPrimaryKeyColumn ` with default value as `NULL`. Immediately after I insert or in a transaction I run  `UPDATE table SET SecondPrimaryKeyColumn = PrimaryKeyColumn WHERE SecondPrimaryKeyColumn IS NULL;`

Answer (score 4):

The first question really is: ***why*** would you need to store the same value in two separate columns in the same table? What do you need this for? Doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me....

Since the value of the `IDENTITY` column is only available once the row has **actually been inserted**, there is **no way** to get that value and set it to another column before the row has indeed been saved to the database table.

That basically leaves three options to get that value and store it somewhere else:

- you can write an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that just set the *other* column to the value that's just been inserted in the `IDENTITY` column
- you could wrap the whole saving process into a stored procedure which you call from your C# code (instead of just saving the object) and you would do the `INSERT` of the row, then get the newly created `IDENTITY` value and update the row again with that new value. But that would cause an `UPDATE` to happen - which you seem to say is impossible for you because of an `UPDATE` trigger (not quite clear on **why** this should be a problem....)
- you can write two lines of C# code to get the `IDENTITY` value after it's been inserted (and available in the `ID` property of your object) and then store the object a second time. But that, too, would cause an `UPDATE` to happen - which you seem to say is impossible for you because of an `UPDATE` trigger (not quite clear on **why** this should be a problem....)

So I guess your best option would be an `INSERT` trigger to do this.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trInsertEmpNews 
ON dbo.EmpNews AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.EmpNews 
    SET DisplaySeq = i.ID
    FROM INSERTED i
    WHERE dbo.EmpNews.ID = i.ID
END
```

Comment: I need to store the same value in other column because i need to update this value for some display purpose but can't perform operation on ID